# How to get React three fiber video texture working in mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, backend, react-three-fiber

I'm currently having issues getting video textures to work within the context of a mobile browser from the react three fiber library. It works with all PC browsers and their emulated mobile versions, however, opening it on mobile does not display anything. The code I used can be viewed below.

```
<mesh
  name="Body_Wallpaper_0001"
  geometry={nodes.Body_Wallpaper_0001.geometry}
  scale={2.03}
  rotation={[0, 0, 0]}
>
  <meshStandardMaterial side={THREE.DoubleSide}>
    <videoTexture attach="map" args={[video]} />
    <videoTexture attach="emissiveMap" args={[video]} />
  </meshStandardMaterial>
</mesh>
```

```
const [video] = useState(() => {
  const vid = document.createElement("video");
  vid.src = TikTok;
  vid.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
  vid.loop = true;
  vid.muted = true;
  vid.play();
  vid.playsInline;
  vid.id = "video";
  return vid;
});
```

since it loads perfectly in all other browsers on PC I would have assumed it would play the video texture on mobile also.

Answer (score 0):

I used this format and it started playing video on mobile
You can see it here [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/video-textures-39hg8?file=/src/App.js:0-32)

```
import React from 'react'
import { Suspense } from 'react'
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { useAspect, useVideoTexture, useTexture } from '@react-three/drei'
import url from "../../assets/videos/vscode-ykdevelops.mov";
import fallbackURL from "../../assets/videos/vscode-ykdevelops.png";
export default function VscodeVideo2() {
    const size = useAspect(1800, 1000)
    return (
        <mesh position={[-1.372, -0.01, 0.465]} rotation={[0, 0.45, 0]}>
            <planeGeometry args={[0.5, 1.01]} />
            <Suspense fallback={<FallbackMaterial url={fallbackURL} />}>
                <VideoMaterial url={url} />
            </Suspense>
        </mesh>
    )
}
function VideoMaterial({ url }) {
    const texture = useVideoTexture(url)
    return <meshBasicMaterial map={texture} toneMapped={false} />
}

function FallbackMaterial({ url }) {
    const texture = useTexture(url)
    return <meshBasicMaterial map={texture} toneMapped={false} />
}
```